# Invalid Json string in HTML report generated via Jenkins pipeline

Tags: json, jenkins, html-reports-jenkins

We're trying to generate HTML reports in the end of our Jenkins pipeline build. The report is supposed to display pie charts. But depending on the machine, the browser throws this error in place of the pie charts:

```
Invalid JSON string:
{"width":"100%",
"height":270,
"title":"1 TestSuite",
"is3D":true,
"fontSize":"12",
"colors":["#5cb85c","#f0ad4e","#5bc0de","#d9534f"],
"pieStartAngle":100,
"backgroundColor":"white",
"titleTextStyle":{"fontSize":"13","color":"#5e5e5e"}
}
```

Our pipeline code (not sure if it's relevant):

```
publishHTML (target: [
allowMissing: false,
alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
keepAll: true,
reportDir: 'tests/src/testresults/',
reportFiles: 'chrome-test-report.html',
reportName: 'Test Report'
])
```

Out Jenkins version: 2.32.1

Comment: Is that html report is working before integrating with Jenkins build process.

Comment: Good question, I'll try this tomorrow